# Как вывести названия города из API

Tags: node.js, express

Как вывести названия города если приходит [ответ](https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=bfe7e973311e421bae184243180312&q=Paris) мне с сервера?

```
{"location":{"name":"Paris","region":"Ile-de-France","country":"France"}
```

Вывожу так

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  let city = req.body.city;
  let url = `https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${city}`;

  request(url, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
      res.render("index", { location: null, error: "Error, please try again1" });
    } else {
      let location = JSON.parse(body);
      if (location == undefined) {
        res.render("index", { location: null, error: "Error, please try again2"});
      } else {
        console.log(location.name);
        let locationText = `It's ${location.name} degrees in ${location.name}!`;
        res.render("index", { location: locationText, error: null });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Но на `index.ejs` выводит `undefined`. Почему он не выводит названия города?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто. Вы запутались в названии переменных. Парсер json отдаёт вам корневой объект, в котором нужно искать `location.name`. А вы запрашиваете название города сразу у корневого объекта.

Поправьте код, например, так:

`let { location } = JSON.parse(body);`